# Cleanup deleted files from VSCode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am connecting Remote server from VScode at my local . I have deleted couple of files from remote machine directory and I can't get rid of this files showing in VScode pane.

Any idea how can I clean-up the files showing with stricked-out in vscode (annoying to see that 94 numbers at left) I tried Stage / Discard in vscode and nothing working as those files already get removed from filesystem .

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These files are tracked by Git,

The entries you see are in the Source Control section and not explorer because of that. Notice the `D`, it means the files which were tracked before are now deleted.

Unless you make a commit, that tracking will be there. So after you make a commit, all those will disappear.

Another option if you are completely redoing the project and want to get rid of the old files, **WARNING: YOU WILL LOSE ALL PREVIOUS TRACKING INFO**

Completely remove the `.git/` directory using `rm -rf .git/` (*nix) or `rmdir /s ./.git/` (windows)

and then do a new

`git init` to start freshly track your new files.

Comment: thanks ... I made a git commit --all at the root of the local directory of my remote node and everything started disappearing since then . thanks for your help